# Can't find "My Work" option for code review in Visual Studio 2015 community edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, collaboration, vs-community-edition

I'm trying to request a code review from another developer on a project hosted in Visual Studio Online using git.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, which according to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx) Microsoft comparison page, supports code review (Under the "Collaboration Tools" heading).

Is this an option I need to turn on? I've looked in the Team Explorer panel, under the Project section and all I see is "Changes", "Branches", "Sync" and "Settings". From the videos I've watched, I expected to see "My Work" in that section too.

[image: My Work missing from panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem also. Apparently My Work is only available in certain versions of Visual Studio:

**My Work** appears only when you have installed Visual Studio Premium or Visual Studio Ultimate.

Also, it won't show up for Git. Only for Team Foundation VC.

[MSDN: Work in Team Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500420.aspx)

Edit: I missed the link in the question, but looks like MS documentation might not be correct (surprise, surprise!) on one or the other. From that link it looks like there is not even a Premium or Ultimate version of 2015 offered. Very confusing. I'm guessing the page I referenced is not correct, even though it says it's for 2015. So I'd assume it's only available in Enterprise version, since in my own case, it did not show up in the Professional version.

Comment: Yeah I've found a few places that say that, am I just reading the comparison in that link wrong? It clearly says Community supports code review. Frustrating...

Comment: It does say Code Review for Community version, but they unfortunately don't specify what features that includes.